# How to translate all django packages in my project

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I'm using some packages in my project such as django-import-export, django-admin-tools, ... but not all of them support my language (Vietnamese) so i want to translate them by myself.

I tried to copy a django.mo file into my 'locate' dir and translate it. It's work, but other packages also has django.mo file.

My question is: is the any way to merge all django.mo file into one, or how to override a package translation file.

P/S: Sorry about my poor English.

Comment: You could contribute to each of those projects individually so everyone can benefit from your translations. You can find [django-import-export](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export) and [django-admin-tools](https://github.com/django-admin-tools/django-admin-tools) on github.

Comment: But my translations must use words that only suitable for my project. On other hand, contribute means i have to wait them accept my pull request, it may take some time.

Comment: Also it's easier to start somewhere. And to have it on my project is easier than to have a development copy for all my dependencies... Not to mention private or commercial projects that are perfectly legal under some popular oss projects.